# Is there a robust test for stochastic dominance between two random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to compare the errors from two statistical models in order to give evidence to one being "better" in terms of lower prediction error than the other.

To formalize this, I thought that a test of stochastic dominance between two collections of random variables (the OOS errors) would be a good idea. Ideally the null hypothesis would be either:

$$\mathbb{H}_0 : P(X>Y) = 0.5$$

$$\mathbb{H'}_0 : F(x) \ge G(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have found resources pointing me to the Kruskal-Wallis test, but unfortunately cannot seem to find a paper explicitly stating and proving one of these (or similar) null hypotheses. Many sources I check simply state that the null is that the medians of the two distributions differ, but this is not what I want to check. Any help is appreciated.

Edit for more information: Essentially I want as minimal assumptions on the data as possible. The two samples $X_1, \dots , X_n$ and $Y_1, \dots , Y_n$ are such that $(X_1, Y_1)$ is independent of $(X_2, Y_2)$, but in general $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are dependent. Also, The $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are all different distributions (so we cannot in particular assume they all come from the same family).

Comment: Your question is quite vague. If you have more details, perhaps they would be helpful. // Would it be enough to know that the mean or median of one model is greater than that of the other? That kind of comparison is more usual. // K-W is usually used to compare _several_ models. Maybe you should look at Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon _two_-sample test, which compares two medians. // 'Robust' can mean tolerance for departure from an assumption, which assumption is in doubt? Normality? Equal variances? If normality, then MWW may be what you want.

Comment: Another idea might be a one-sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov test comparing data from two independent models. // Can you be more specific about the data you are analyzing?  So far this is a little like calling up a dermatologist and saying "I have the pinkish, itchy, rashy thing on my leg, what should I put on it?"

Comment: Essentially I want as minimal assumptions on the data as possible. The two samples X_1, ..., X_n and Y_1, ..., Y_n are such that (X_1, Y_1) is independent of (X_2, Y_2), but in general X_i and Y_i are dependent. Also, The X_i and Y_i are all different distributions (so we cannot in particular assume they all come from the same family).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Comment and edit, you have paired data. You don't seem to
feel comfortable assuming data are normal. Consequently, I have two
possibilities to suggest: (1) A one-sample Wilcoxon signed rank test on 
$D_i = X_i - Y_i$ to test $H_0: \eta_D \le 0$ against $H_a: \eta_D > 0,$
where $\eta_D$ is the median of the population from which the $D_i$ are taken.
(2) A permutation test, (c) simple linear regression to see if intercept is above 0.

**Fake data:** In order to illustrate, I need some data. I generate data
for $n = 50$ pairs with $X_i \stackrel{indep}{\sim} \mathsf{Gamma}(shape=2, rate = 1/5)$ (a right-skewed distribution with positive values),
$D_i \stackrel{indep}{\sim}\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=.5, \sigma=3),$ and $Y_i = X_i + D_i.$

These are for illustration only. I'm not trying to guess the nature of your actual data. Here are means and standard deviations of the three variables,
their (high positive) correlation,
a look at the first six pairs (and their differences), a histogram of
the differences (more positive than negative), and a scatterplot of $(X,Y)$-pairs. The scatterplot shows
that most points lie above the 45-degree line, indicating that $Y$'s tend to
be larger than $X$'s.

```
set.seed(112)
x = round(rgamma(50, 2, 1/5), 2) + 5
d = round(rnorm(50, .5, 3), 2);  y = x + d
mean(x);  mean(y);  mean(d)
## 14.6536
## 15.4032
## 0.7496
## sd(x); sd(y); sd(d)
## 6.193094
## 7.089804
## 2.872664
cor(x,y)
## 0.9151847

head(cbind(x, y, d))
           x     y     d
##[1,] 10.70 15.07  4.37
##[2,] 29.74 24.02 -5.72
##[3,]  6.82  9.72  2.90
##[4,]  7.19  5.46 -1.73
##[5,] 10.29  6.70 -3.59
##[6,] 15.52 16.18  0.66
```

[image]

**Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test.**

This test shows that the median population difference is likely positive.
Specifically, the P-value of about 3% (< 5%) indicates rejection the
null hypothesis.

```
wilcox.test(d, alte="g")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  d 
V = 829, p-value = 0.0326
alternative hypothesis: true location is greater than 0
```

**Permutation Test.**
Section 3 of [*this paper*](http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v18n1/eudey.pdf) in the *Journal of Statistics Education* gives an introductory account of permutation tests on paired data.
Similar permutation tests on my fake data again show that the $Y$'s tend
to be larger than the $X$'s. Various methods of measuring the differences between $(X,y)$-pairs are possible. It is not necessary to assume that 
the variables have any particular distribution.

**Regression.** A simple linear regression of the $Y$'s on the $X$'s shows that the regression line lies above the 45-degree line in the plot. A formal test
of this is part of the usual output of regression procedures. However, the most
elementary regression procedure assumes that 'errors' about the regression line are normally distributed (but not that the $X$'s are normally distributed).

*Conclusion:* I cannot tell you exactly what test to use without knowing more about your data. But from what you have said, it is reasonable to hope that considering the methods I have mentioned here will put you on the right track.

Comment: The issue though is that even if the $X-Y$ is not symmetric, the two could still be "equivalent". X and Y are both errors generated by two models, so I want to be able to say that one is "usually" lower than the other. It's possible for Signed Rank to show significance for a bimodal distribution about 0, but with one of the "bell curves" bigger than the other. In such a case, the models would still be comparable with no clear winner. I want a test that provides significance when it is clear that one is going to be lower than the other usually.